# show that the remainder of $\frac{2^{100}}{23}$ is $2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

As stated in the title, I'm supposed to show that $$2^{100}\equiv 2 \pmod {23}$$

I can't really wrap my head around this. At first I thought the book said that $a \equiv a^x$ no matter the exponent, but this doesn't seem to hold true since $2^1, 2^2, 2^3$ etc all seem to have different remainders when divided by 23.

So how "do" you arrive at this conclusion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know, or can you look up, [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)?

Comment: I have "difficulties" (I'm naturally suspicious) with working with things I cannot prove, the proof of Fermat's Theorem is not until next semester. Is that the only way to solve this?

Comment: Well, you can try a smaller exponent to begin with. For example, $2^5$ is congruent to 9 mod 23. And you can start building from there ...

Comment: Ok, so look at the powers of $2 \pmod {23}$.  It won't take you long to find the least positive exponent $a$ such that $2^a\equiv 1 \pmod {23}$.  Take it from there.

Comment: You could simply cube $\large \,3 (2^{\large 3})\equiv 1\,$ to get $\large \,2^{\large 11}\equiv 1\pmod{23},\,$ see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $2^{100}\equiv 2 \bmod {23}$ iff $2^{99}\equiv 1 \bmod {23}$. So try $2^k \bmod {23}$ for $k=1,9,11$, the proper divisors of $99$.

Comment: This post is confusing but I ended up doing something similar, I went through the powers of to and at $2^{11}$ I ended up with a remainder of 1 for$ 2^{11}$. This "should" mean that $(2^{11}^9 \equiv 1^9$ and that the remainder is still = 1, but why would this imply that $2^{100} \equiv 2 \mod 23$?

Comment: @Magnus, $2^{100}\equiv 2\cdot 2^{99}\equiv 2 \cdot 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick without using Fermat's Little Theorem that can arrive at the answer you need quickly (commonly done in computer science for optimization):

We have $100 = 64 + 32 + 4$.

$$
2^{2}\equiv 4 \bmod 23
$$
$$
2^{4}\equiv 4^2 \equiv 16 \bmod 23
$$
$$
2^{8}\equiv 16^2 \equiv 3 \bmod 23
$$
$$
2^{16}\equiv 3^2 \equiv 9 \bmod 23
$$
$$
2^{32}\equiv 9^2 \equiv 12 \bmod 23
$$
$$
2^{64}\equiv 12^2 \equiv 6\bmod 23
$$
Therefore:

$$
2^{100}\equiv 2^4\times2^{32}\times2^{64} \equiv 16\times12\times6 \equiv 2\bmod 23
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Fermat's theorem.

You can also easily do it by hand in the following manner:

if you do the repeated product of $2$ modulo $23$ you get

$1,2,4,8,16,9,18,13,3,6,12$

and next $2 \times 12 = 24 \equiv 1 \mod 23.$

As you see, the powers of 2 form a cyclic group of order 11. Then you have to see that $100 \mod 11 = 1$, because $100 = 9 \times 11 +1$.

This means that $2^{100} = 2^1 = 2.$

Comment: $100 = ? \times 11 + 1$  ?

Comment: Oups sorry, I correct it right away, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\bmod 23\!:\ 2\equiv 5^{\large 2}\overset{(\ \ )^{\LARGE 11}\!\!\!\!}\Longrightarrow\ 2^{\large 11}\!\equiv \overbrace{5^{\large 22}\equiv 1}^{\rm Fermat}\,$  $\overset{(\ \ )^{\LARGE 9}\!\!}\Longrightarrow\, 2^{\large 99}\equiv 1\overset{\large \times\ 2\ }\Longrightarrow\ 2^{\large 100}\equiv 2$

**Edit** $ $ Comments reveal little Fermat is unknown. Instead $ \ 1\equiv 3(2^{\large 3}) \overset{(\ \ )^{\LARGE 3}\!\!}\Longrightarrow\  1\equiv 4(2^{\large 9})\equiv 2^{\large 11}$

**Alternatively** We can  enumerate  small powers of $,2\,$ by successively doubling, starting with $\,2^4\equiv 16,\,$ then $\,\ 2(16)\equiv 32\equiv \color{#0a0}9,\ $ $\, 2(9)\equiv 18\equiv \color{#90f}{-5},\,\ldots$

$$\!\!\begin{array}{|r|r|}
\hline
n & 4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\color{#c00}{11}\\
\hline
2^{\large n}\bmod 23 &16&\color{#0a0}9&\color{#90f}{-5}&-10&3&6&12&\color{#c00}1\\ 
\hline
\end{array}\qquad$$

Comment: The first method is a special case of [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick you can use to evaluate any large power $\ a^b\ $, say, modulo a moderately sized one $\ c\ $, say, reasonably easily.  The trick is to write $\ b\ $ in binary form, $\ b = 2^{b_1} + 2^{b_2} + \dots + 2^{b_r}\ $, say, with $\ b_1 < b_2 < \dots < b_r\ $, compute the values $\ a^2\ (\mbox{mod } c), a^{2^2} (\mbox{mod } c), \dots, a^{2^{b_r}} (\mbox{mod } c)\ $ by successively squaring $\ a\ (\mbox{mod }c)\ $, then computing $\ a^b\ (\mbox{mod } c) = a^{2^{b_1}}a^{2^{b_2}} \dots a^{2^{b_r}} (\mbox{mod } c)\ $.  For your problem, $\ a=2, b=100\ $ and $\ c=23\ $, and $\ 100 = 2^2 + 2^5 + 2^6\ $, so you only have to compute $6$ successive squares of $\ 2\ (\mbox{mod } 23)\ $, which are $\ 4, 16, 3, 9, 12\ $ and $\ 6\ (\mbox{mod }23)\ $, and multiply the second, fifth and sixth of these together: $16\cdot12\cdot6 \ (\mbox{mod }23)\ $, which should give you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Euler Totient (or Fermat’s Little Theorem), we see that
$$2^{\phi(23)}=2^{22}\equiv1\pmod(23)$$

Hence,
$$2^{100}=(2^{22})^4\cdot2^{12}\equiv1^4\cdot2^{12}\pmod{23}$$
$$=(2^6)^2=64^2\equiv(-5)^2=25\equiv2\pmod{23}$$

Answer (score 0):

As
$$2^{11}=32^2\cdot2\equiv9^2\cdot2\equiv12\cdot2\equiv1\pmod{23}$$

We see that
$$2^{100}=(2^{11})^9\cdot2\equiv1^9\cdot2=2\pmod{23}$$